# How to get currently save documents _id in Node js & mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working with node js & mongodb. Current I need some help to retrive _id for a saved document.

My Code :

```
var user= new User();
user.name = 'Name';
user.email = 'test@gmail.com';
user.save(function(err){
    if(!err)
     {
          console.log('Saved');
          // Need this documents _id
     }
})
```

How can I get this _id ? Need help for this.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add second arg for callback in save method.

```
var user= new User();
        user.name = 'Name';
        user.email = 'test@gmail.com';
        user.save(function(err, user){ // here you must add user 
            if(!err)
             {
                  console.log('Saved');
                  user._id // id for user 
             }
        })
```